# Can two 10/2 cables be combined to use as a 10/3?

Tags: wiring, shed

I'm trying to run wire to my shed 30 feet from house. I thought it would be nice to have two circuits, one for lights and one for heavier current applications.  So I ran two 10/2 18inches deep in PVC... and now I read I can't run two cables to the shed. ugh! It's buried. Is it possible to leave it and electrician can configure the two 10/2 into the equivalent of a 10/3? Or do I have to dig this trench again and put in a single 10/3?

Comment: Wow, I wish you'd talked to us first.  For less than you spent on dual 10/2, you could've bought #2Al feeder and a subpanel to distribute it! In the future, don't hesitate to ask "Is this a good plan?" before you buy anything.  Especially wire - Harper's Law, buy the wire *last*.   Now that said... **what size is your conduit?**

Comment: 1 inch pvc, yeah it was difficult getting those two cables through. ugh!

Comment: Schedule 40 or 80? Determines available fill.

Answer (score 5):

No you can't combine them. If you (as code requires) finished assembling the conduit before pulling wire into it you should be able to pull the old wire out without digging up the conduit.

But seriously, don't pull cables into conduit. Two cables were quite likely over maximum fill allowance and difficult. Pull individual THWN conductors.

Answer (score 3):

#### The Problem

> I'm trying to run wire to my shed 30 feet from house.

Should install a subpanel. Up-front cost, but long-term benefits.

> I thought it would be nice to have two circuits, one for lights and one for heavier current applications.

Which also has the benefit that if one of your tools trips a breaker, the lights stay on.

> So I ran 2 10/2 18inches deep in PVC... and now I read I can't run two cables to the shed. ugh!

Correct. You can only run one of each type of *circuit*. You actually shouldn't be running **any** cables. You should run individual wires instead - much easier to do. But still limited by *circuits*. You can run one each of (for example):

- 120V (i.e., your usual /2)
- 240V (/2 used with a double-breaker and no neutral)
- 120V/240V (aka MWBC w /3)
- Switched 120V (shed lights turned on/off from house or shed instead of just shed)

But the best solution is one **big** circuit running to a subpanel. Then you install as many smaller circuits as you need in the subpanel.

> It's buried. Is it possible to leave it and electrician can configure the 2 10/2 into the equivalent of a 10/3?

As a general rule (independent of the shed, conduit, etc.) you can't do that. The reason is that all the power (e.g., two hots and neutral) have to be running together. That means either a single cable or loose wires in conduit. It is true that loose wires in conduit, if there are other circuits (can't do that here, but can in many other situations) mean the partner hots and neutral might end up an inch apart, but that is allowed and is a bit different from being in an actual separate cable.

> Or do I have to dig this trench again and put in a single 10/3?

If you did this properly in conduit ("PVC") then you should **not** need to dig the trench again. That is the whole point of conduit.

#### The Solution

Remove the cables. Run 4 wires - back/red/white/green (actually black and red could be both black). But the question is what *size*? That will depend on your conduit, and the size you run will determine the capacity. But since you managed to get two *cables* into the conduit, it is probably large enough that you can run something much larger than 10 AWG and put in a decent size subpanel. And then you can run whatever you want - tools, lights, air conditioner, etc.

Note that there are other requirements that come into play once your are in subpanel land, that may not apply with a single circuit:

- Shutoff switch - but a main breaker in a subpanel will do that just fine.
- Grounding - you likely need separate ground rounds at the shed.

Note that GFCI will most likely be required, and that could be done either in the subpanel or using a GFCI breaker in the main panel to feed the subpanel.

Answer (score 2):

### What Code says.

Outdoors you must use UF cable (gray).  You can't use NM (orange or white). So if you used NM, this has to be replaced *anyway* because it's going to fail.

The receptacle and lighting circuits to the shed must be 15A or 20A.  You cannot put those on 30A breakers, so #10 wire is really wasted on this.  The distance isn't far enough for voltage drop to matter.

For conduit size, flat cable is treated same as round cable of the wide dimension (because it twists).  UF being very flat, it is very demanding on conduit space.  For two 10/2 UF cables, 1-1/4" conduit is *a tiny bit too small*.  It would be physically impossible to pull it through conduit any smaller than that.

Code also requires that **conduit must be built pullable** - that is, it must be built so you can pull the wires out at any time, and swap them for other wires.  That means broad sweeps at corners, all conduit body and junction box covers remain accessible forever and not buried (e.g. under drywall), and bends between access points be limited to four 90's.

### 1" conduit suggests you assembled the conduit around the wires.

I.E. sleeving the conduit over the cables, one stick at a time, as you lay the conduit.  I do A LOT of conduit work, and *man oh man*, that sounds like way too much work!

Anyway that is a Code violation for at least two reasons: first it is *possible, even easy* to build conduit that is not pullable. And second, it is easy to damage the cable that way, e.g. by melting the insulation with PVC cement.

### So, here are my reco's.

First, if you used NM cable, that's a deal-breaker. That cable must come out of there (and get sold on Craigslist if you can get it out without destroying it).

Second, if the conduit was not constructed properly (not pullable), you *should* dig out the wrong sections (only at the ends, surely) and replace them with correct work.

With those things corrected, we have a shot at a "cheapie" solution.

### Option 1: put a switch on one circuit and call it "lighting".

**You can only have 1 circuit per building, *except* for certain uses**.  One of those uses is a **switched circuit** for lighting.  If one of the circuits *powered lights* (and maybe a few receptacles, that's fine), and that was wired to a switch in a sensible place, then you can tell the inspector *"I want to be able to control the shop lights / outside lights from the house, so I don't have to put on my galoshes"*.  There you go.

If you happen to put a dust collector and a  bunch of tool battery chargers on that 'lighting' circuit *too*, well, that's allowed.

### Option 2: Yank the wire out and put in better wire.

Install a subpanel, then run a 4-wire feeder to it.

Once your conduit is fit to be pulled,  you can simply pull the faulty cables out, and install any *individual wires* that will [legally fit](https://www.southwire.com/calculator-conduit) in  your conduit.

Individual wires must be in conduit and can't run through open spaces.  In that case, either extend the conduit the full run, or fit junction box(es) and transition to a legal cable type.

For instance you could run copper 6-3 NM (55A) to a junction box, use "MAC Block Connectors" to splice to #6 Al THWN wires (50A) and take those on via conduit to the subpanel.  You'll be amazed how inexpensive the aluminum is.

Or in 1" Sched 40, you could run 3x #2 aluminum + a #8 bare copper ground (space is pretty tight).  That's good for 90 amps.

Sched 80 you could only do #4, only good for 65A (breakered at 70A).